# jQuery - how to use .replace with jQuery obj

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.selector.active').each(function() {
  $(this).replace(/\s/g, '_');
}
```

What is supposed to happen is: each element with `.selector` class that has `.active`, replace the white spaces "`\s`" with "`_`"

What I am running into is that `.replace` does not work with `$(this)` as `$(this)` is a jQuery obj and `.replace` is not a jQuery function. I've also tried `this.replace(/\s/g, '_');` but it also err'd...

I am wondering how I can accomplish what I am setting out to do (replace white spaces with underscore for each element with `.selector.active` as the classes). jQuery or plain JS - it doesn't matter.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to replace the text inside the element, in which case you need to get and set the text;

```
$('.selector.active').each(function() {
  $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '_'));
}
```

EDIT: Let me break this out a bit so you understand what it's doing

```
$('.selector.active').each(function() {
  var innerText = $(this).text();
  var replacedText = innerText.replace(/\s/g, '_');
  //now set the new text in the element
  $(this).text(replacedText);
}
```

The first code I posted just puts it all together.

Comment: thank you, this does not seem to be working... I also tried `$(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '_'));` but that did not work... (I tested it in a `console.log`)

Comment: Just made an edit to explain the `.text()` method a bit. `console.log(innerText)` should show the text of the element. That is, if it has text.

Comment: thank you. I understand it now, I was also debugging the wrong thing... Thanks for your help! this fixed it